# How to display EditText blinking cursor in TextView?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, responsive

I planned to use TextView instead of Button and EditText(following my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580241/how-to-create-auto-resize-edittext-and-button)). But when I am using it as EditText How can I represent blinking cursor of EditText in TextView?
In fact I want to use TextView as an EditText because EditText doesn't have AutoSizeText property before SDK 26 but TextView does.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look on this attribut **android:textEditPasteWindowLayout**

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Your text"
android:hint="My hint"
android:textEditPasteWindowLayout="@layout/editextView"
style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"/>
```